# How to fix hover

Tags: html, css

I was doing my homework and I am stuck at the moment with implementing a hover feature. If I have only 1 button and 1 panel everything works perfectly but when I add 2nd button everything breaks completely.

I have tried replacing position: absolute, editing margin but it couldn't help.

```css
.block {
  width: 600px;
  height: 500px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 4px;
}

.btn-1 {
  width: 296px;
  height: 163px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  background-color: #d63;
  z-index: 4;
  position: absolute;
  border-color: black;
}

.btn-2 {
  width: 296px;
  height: 163px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  background-color: #d63;
  z-index: 4;
  position: absolute;
  border-color: black;
  margin-top: 164px;
}

.panel {
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #d63;
  z-index: 3;
  position: absolute;
  transition: 0.7s;
}

.btn-1:hover+.panel {
  margin-left: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="block">
      <button class="btn-1"> </button>
      <button class="btn-2"> </button>
      <div class="panel"> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I expect that 2nd button won't break everything and hover will work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add the 2nd button between them, the 1st button and the panel are no longer [adjacent siblings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) (the `+` operator). Use the [general sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) (`~`) instead:

```
.btn-1:hover~.panel {
  margin-left: 300px;
}
```

**Example:**

```css
.block {
  width: 600px;
  height: 500px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 4px;
}

.btn-1 {
  width: 296px;
  height: 163px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  background-color: #d63;
  z-index: 4;
  position: absolute;
  border-color: black;
}

.btn-2 {
  width: 296px;
  height: 163px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  background-color: #d63;
  z-index: 4;
  position: absolute;
  border-color: black;
  margin-top: 164px;
}

.panel {
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #d63;
  z-index: 3;
  position: absolute;
  transition: 0.7s;
}

.btn-1:hover~.panel {
  margin-left: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="block">
      <button class="btn-1"> </button>
      <button class="btn-2"> </button>
      <div class="panel"> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```